# How to map xml to bean without root element specifying?

Tags: java, jaxb

Suppose I have a class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class A {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    String field;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    List<String> list;
}
```

I need to get next json representation:

```
{
   "field": "someFiled",
   "list": ["a", "b"]
}
```

But instead of desirable json I get

```
{
  "A": {
       "field": "someFiled",
       "list": ["a", "b"]
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What JSON implementation are you using?

Comment: Spring default impl. I think its Jackson.

Comment: It would seem that you have turned root-wrapping on. Google "[spring Jackson root wrap](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+Jackson+root+wrap&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" to find more information.